# Magento Event (Which event is called on Index?)

Tags: magento, observer-pattern, enterprise, mage

As stated in the question, which event is fired when someone goes into the admin panel and selects reindex data for Catalog Search Index?

I tried running grep on my command shell and I cannot seem to get that to work (to get a list of events).  I've tried looking at event lists and can't find the correct one.

I would tend to think that the event catalogindex_plain_reindex_after would be fired, but I have tried this and that is not the case...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: tried to log all events?

Comment: I'm somewhat new to Magento.  how could I do that?

Comment: [http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/quick-tip-finding-events-or-where-has-cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before-gone/](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/quick-tip-finding-events-or-where-has-cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before-gone/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot find any particular event dispatch you can always get the following event on controller:

```
<controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_index_process_massReindex>...</controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_index_process_massReindex>
```

and in the observer you can get the controller params as:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getData('controller_action')->getRequest()->getParam('some_id_or_variable');
```

where 'some_id_or_variable' is the value you want to get from request params.

Comment: you will not receive this event if this functionality is executed trough other models directly

Comment: correct I agree but the question specifically asked "which event is fired when someone goes into the admin panel and selects reindex data for Catalog Search Index" ... but I agree it is not a very good practice.